# Interpreting interaction effect when the direct effect is fully mediated

Tags: interaction, mediation

I have established that the effect of an independent variable X on outcome Y is fully mediated by a second independent variable M using the approach by Baron and Kenny (1986). However, the theory suggests that the direct effect of X on Y may be moderated by a third variable Z. In fact, the results show that the moderation effect X*Z is statistically significant. How do I interpret this result if there is no direct effect of X on Y (i.e. it is fully mediated by M)?

Comment: I am not clear on the problem. There are 2 mediating variables, Z and M?

Comment: Not really, M is a mediating variable and Z is a moderating variable. At first, we have hypothesized that there is a (1) direct effect of X on Y, (2) the effect of X on Y is moderated by Z. But we have discovered that that the direct effect of X is fully mediated by M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interpret it pretty straightforwardly. There is still an effect of X on Y, and of X*Z on Y, unless there is some context-specific reason why the standard interpretation is hard.

Interpret the effect of $X$ and $X\times Z$ as: given that a binary Z==1, then the effect of X on Y is $(\beta_{X\times Z} + \beta_{X})$, and it is fully mediated by $M$. When Z==0 the effect of X on Y is $\beta_{X}$, and again it is fully mediated by $M$.

The effect $\beta_{X\times Z}$ is the extra effect of X on Y beyond $\beta_{X}$ that we observe when Z==1.

A mediator doesn't change the fact that X affects Y. There is always some notional mediation between two variables depending on how granular you conceive of the causal process.

And of course make sure you include the uninteracted $Z$ in your model also. Always include all constitutive terms in your regressions.